# Deploy my local Strongloop Code on AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, putty, strongloop

I need to deploy my code for Strongloop onto AWS EC2.
I have created a instance on AWS server and is up running.
But now I don't know how to transfer my code to AWS EC2.
Also I'm using Putty command line.

Comment: Are you able to access via SSH? if yes then you may transfer using sftp or scp command

Comment: I'm using Putty Command Line. I have logged in to my aws ec2. Now how could I proceed further with all node installing and code deploying

Comment: You did not specify your AWS EC2 OS. You may check `cat /etc/*-release` to see OS and architecture of OS. Have you installed node.js ? If not then follow https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

Comment: its Amazon Linux. And I haven't installed Node.js yet

Answer (score 1):

You should login using SSH client like putty or you may use git bash as ssh client

```
yum update

yum install curl

curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -
```

for 4.x, you may refer install [nodejs on fedora](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#enterprise-linux-and-fedora) because Amazon Linux based on fedora.

Now check nodejs and npm version using `node -v` and `npm -v` after that transfer file from local to server. You may use sftp client like [winscp](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php) or [filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client) to transfer file from local to server.

Note: Please do not transfer node_modules folder. After successful transfer, login to server using ssh via putty and then go to inside project using `cd` command and then `npm install`

#### Another solution for file transfer using command line

Download [git](https://git-scm.com/download/win) & install and then start git bash and then use following scp command (delete node_modules folder before transfer)

```
scp -i myAmazonKey.pem -r nodejsapp/ ec2-user@EC2_IP_ADDRESS:~/.
```

After successful transfer, login to ssh via following SSH command

```
ssh -i myAmazonKey.pem ec2-user@EC2_IP_ADDRESS
```

and then go to inside project and then install dependencies

```
cd nodejsapp/
npm install
```

I hope this help you

#### Another solution for file transfer using git

```
ssh -i myAmazonKey.pem ec2-user@EC2_IP_ADDRESS
yum install git
```

check git install successfully `git --version` if yes then clone repository

```
git clone yourRepo
cd yourRepo
npm install
```

Comment: I have installed Node.js and npm on EC2. And also connected to my server from Filezilla.

Comment: Wanted to know that should I transfer .git and .idea files to EC2 As my local project is sync with Bitbucket Private Repo

Comment: No, you do not need to transfer these folders/files, transfer only required files and folder in application. I would like to recommend to use 3rd solution in above answer if you familiar with git

Comment: one more thing. How could I start my Strongloop application on AWS EC2. I started using node server.js and also the server is running on AWS EC2 showing Web server listening at: http://0.0.0.0:3001/
ENVIRONMENT : development. But when I open my EC2 url to see my api explorer. It isn't showing up

Comment: You need to enable port used in application like 3001 in your case. You may need to add 3001 port in [AWS console security group](https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-west-2#SecurityGroups:sort=groupId)

Comment: Actually in my Security group I have enable all the IP Addresses. Then does it need to specify an extra Port Number